# Crop output pdf page to \fbox

Tags: macros, pdftex, dvips, ps2pdf

Is there is any way to crop the output pdf to the `\fbox{}` with LaTeX Macros?
I wrote a macro to test such examples something like:

```
\newcommand{\inlinebox}[1]{
\fbox{#1}%
<--crop the output page to the equation content-->
\clearpage%
}
```

Minimal example of LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\inlinebox}[1]{
\fbox{#1}%    
<--crop the output page to the equation content-->
\clearpage%
}
\begin{document}
\inlinebox{$\widetilde{\mathbf{l}}$}
\end{document}
```

Expected PDF output is something like:

[image]

I am facing some issues with `preview` package and I cannot also use `standalone` class so I need to wrote my own macro to handle such small tasks.

*NOTE: I use `latex` `dvips` `ps2pdf` cycle*.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\widetilde{\mathbf{l}}$}

\end{document}
```

I leave some grey border to show that the generated PDF just contains the box

[image]

You can also do, but with not so nice output

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\fbox{$\widetilde{\mathbf{l}}$}

\end{document}
```

Then run

```
latex file.tex
dvips file.dvi -o
ps2pdf file.ps
pdfcrop file.pdf
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i mentioned above that i cannot use `standalone` due to i have to follow the in house style of my organization.

Comment: @MohamedSayed The output size cannot be controlled by a macro like that.

Comment: ok i understand that but what is the alternative solution for that issue? what is your suggestions ?

Comment: I am trying to use `pdfcrop file.pdf` but i got an error `The Perl interpreter could not be found` I downloaded it and installed but with no success.